# Left join subqueries gives SQL Error [1100] [HY000]: ERROR: 'ON A.XX= B.KEY2' error ^ found "ON" (at char 1) expecting a keyword

Tags: sql

Here's my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM SELECT (KEY1, XX, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY KEY1 ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS YES
FROM TABLE1) A
LEFT JOIN SELECT (KEY2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DATA, KEY2 ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS NO
FROM TABLE2) B
ON A.XX= B.KEY2
```

And my error:

> `SQL Error [1100] [HY000]: ERROR: 'ON A.XX= B.KEY2' error ^ found "ON" (at char 1) expecting a keyword`

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried including nested select into the bracket?

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT KEY1, XX, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY KEY1 ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS YES FROM TABLE1) A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT KEY2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DATA, KEY2 ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS NO FROM TABLE2) B
ON A.XX= B.KEY2;
```

Comment: Hello, yes that was my first option but still have the same error